# sqlite with where clause not working in android

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

```
Log.e("Thinhdt1", qb.buildQuery(new String[] { "sum(money)" }, 
             "category = ?", new String[] {category}, null, null, null, null));

     Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(
         "Exchange",
         new String[] { "sum(money)" },
         "category = ?" , 
         new String[] {category},
         null,
         null,
         null
         );
```

Log in logcat() : SELECT sum(money) FROM Exchange WHERE (category = ?)

please , find errors help me .
Thanks .

Comment: What's the error in Logcat?

Comment: You should kept the String variables with in the single quotes..While you are querying database.

Comment: I updated the query : "category = '"+ category +"'" , why program will error . you can help me , find bugs . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(
     "Exchange",
     new String[] { "sum(money) as sum" },
     "category = ?" , 
     new String[] {category},
     null,
     null,
     null
     );
```

Comment: Did you try the the solution exactly as I posted.

Comment: why , in Logcat print : SELECT sum(money) FROM Exchange WHERE (category = 'Thu') , this query correct , but program execute error. I don't understand . You can help me , find error . Thanks

Comment: I asked you what kind of error? Is the cursor empty or your app stop? If you do not use the solution I provide you will get an empty cursor.

Comment: program stopped when I try to access the above query .<pre>    .java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fm/com.example.fm.ThongKeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException <code> . You support very fast , I hope you can find bugs help me .

Comment: So it is not the query that cause problem. You get a null pointer exception somewhere else, post your code and logcat, otherwise nobody can help. You should accept this answer and then post another question with your code and logcat. The title of your question could be like this "Application crash, NPE"

Comment: You must be Vietnamese, send me an email. I will help you out. I am going to sleep now.

Comment: Thank you , I checked application and find the problem . Nice to meet you , I come from Viet Nam. What's your email ?